Could not find any result for the supplied address or coordinates
I am building a taxi app with flutter for my school so far everything works well on the android side but on the ios side, when i type an address on the google placeAutocomplete it returns this error

Unhandled Exception: Could not find any result for the supplied
address or coordinates.
#0      GeocodingIOS._handlePlatformException (package:geocoding_ios/geocoding_ios.dart:71:9)
#1      GeocodingIOS.locationFromAddress (package:geocoding_ios/geocoding_ios.dart:41:7)

It was returning the same error on android too until i enabled and unrestricted the Place Api and Geocoding Api on google cloud platform it stoped and now everything works very well in the android version I am only getting this error on the IOS version of my app.

I have spent days searching the internet for a solution i have not find any yet.
